# sed + delete all comment lines and when line match specific word

Tags: linux, redhat, sed

I created this sed in order to delete the comment lines lines from fstab ( comment can ne with begin of space or TAB etc )

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*#/d' /etc/fstab
```

in my case I want to add also the condition to remove the comment lines that contain the word data

example

```
# UUID=381ff65e-01e0-4e14-9f2a-9e493d13ae45 /data/sdb ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
#UUID=cbe83dcd-3a01-4160-b1cd-f959106ee3de /data/sdc ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
```

so I tried this syntax

```
 sed '/data/ /^[[:blank:]]*#/d' /etc/fstab
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unknown command: `/'
```

what I need to improve in my sed command ?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you search for is:

```
sed '/data/d ; /^[[:blank:]]*#/d' /etc/fstab
```

The semicolon separate two commands.

If you want to have logical AND between two conditions you can use `awk` command (have no idea about `sed`:

```
awk '!/^[[:blank:]]*#/ || !/data/ {print}' /etc/fstab
```

Comment: I think you not understand what I need , sed will delete the line when both conditions are true , means the line is comment and line include the word data

Comment: your sed delete the comment lines even if its not include the data word

Comment: @KingDavid, added command to delete with AND condition

Comment: yes but the question was to do it with sed not with awk!!

Comment: @KingDavid: I suggest `sed '/^[[:blank:]]*#.*data/d' /etc/fstab`.